# Display custom post type by custom taxonomy

Tags: query-posts

I've got a custom post type called "listing" a custom  taxonomy called "listing_tags".  I'd like to display the listing post type posts that have a listing_tag called "basic".  Is this possible?  I thought something like the following would get me started, but no luck at all.

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('listings_tags');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'listing',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'listings_tags',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->basic,
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
        endwhile;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `tax_query` `terms` parameter.

Try:

```
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'listings_tags',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
        ),
 ),
```

And if you want posts from just `basic`, there's no need for getting terms and loopin through. All you can do is `WP_Query` with `tax_query` `terms` parameter as `'basic'`.